# how can I use a pgsql query with JS

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

I'm working on an application and using google charts so I can add statistics , the problem so far is I wanna retrieve data from my database and put it in the javascript functions ! I just don't know how I can mix two different languages and I'm coding with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'),
        array(...whatever data you extracted from the db...)
    );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT); ?>
    );
</script>
```

Note JSON_HEX_TAG is necessary to ensure there is no `</script>` end-tag in the encoded string and JSON_HEX_AMP would be necessary if XHTML were in use. JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE should not be used as it would allow U+2028 and U+2029 characters which are valid in JSON but not in JavaScript.

An alternative approach if you want to avoid inline JavaScript elements and mistreating JSON as JavaScript would be to pass the data through the DOM:

```
<div id="something" data-data="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)); ?>">

...

var json = document.getElementById('something').getAttribute('data-data');
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch all the data from postgres in php before feeding it your html templates.

1) http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php

2) Any template engine or your own plain html files with variables in it. For example: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: for instance in this script 
`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);`
i want to replace 1000 with a value of some column in my database